I would like to apply a macro to a worksheet with the thesis below, using a selection of the tabs, namely the 3rd to 78th
I would like to apply a macro to a worksheet with the thesis below. Now I don't want it to run on every tab, but a selection of the tabs, namely the 3rd to 78th. Who can help me adjust the script so that this works? (Excel)


I'm not a professional programmer, I'm a teacher. My knowledge about programming in macro Excel is limited.

Please copy the code and paste it into your question. Having to read the code from a picture really doesn't help. If possible, also include output your macro is producing vs the expected output.

Also, you can delete any line that has ScrollRow in it, as that is only for a visual effect and just slows it down.

Welcome hilde! Please, don't post a screenshot
